# How to change IP-address of the Synology NAS-station when using VPN-connection?

Tags: vpn, ip, gateway, l2tp, synology

I have set up VPN-connection (L2TP/IPSec) at our office lately. The main thing is that our employees could access Synology NAS-station from their home. VPN-connection works great, but the problem is with the IP-address of the NAS-station.

IP-addresses:

LAN x.x.10.10

WLAN x.x.11.10

DMZ x.x.13.10

At the moment NAS-station finds from ip x.x.13.10:5000 when I use VPN-connection. Without VPN-connection IP is x.x.10.10:5000 (LAN). IP-address should be x.x.10.10:5000 because it would be easier for the employees that IP-address is same at office and at home. Our firewall is ZyWALL 35.

Any ideas?

Comment: a VPN connection should not 'change' the ip address of anything in you LAN - can you explain why it's changing?

Comment: Because our VPN-connection uses DMZ (then NAS-station finds from ip-address x.x.13.10). Whereas our employees access files from NAS-station at the office and its ip-address is x.x.10.10. 

The problem:
It's difficult to remember different ip-addresses and when to use them (for the employees).